# Expected 'options' to be an object or undefined, got function

Tags: javascript, discord

here is my code pls help. it says Expected 'options' to be an object or undefined, got function. i think it has something to do with the port but idk pls help. also, when i put the number in directly, i get the same error except it says number instead of function at the end. help!! heres code:

```
const {Client, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js')
 
const bot = new Client()
 
const util = require('minecraft-server-util')

const ip = 'private ip im not gonna tell'
 
const token = 'private token im not gonna tell'
 
const PREFIX = '~'
 
bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Bot has come online.')
})
 
bot.on('message', message =>{
 
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
 
    switch(args[0]){
        case 'server':
 
            util.ping(ip, { port: 25565 }).then((response) => {
                const embed = new embed()
                .setTitle('Server Status')
                .addField('Server IP', reponse.host)
                .addField('Server Version', reponse.version)
                .addField('Online Players', reponse.onlinePlayers)
                .addField('Max Players', reponse.maxPlayers)
                            
                message.channel.send(Embed)
            }).catch((error) => {
                throw error;
            });
            
 
    }
 
})
 
bot.login(token)
```

Comment: You need to implement the fixes recommended in the answer the last time you asked this.

Comment: @CertainPerformance i did... they didnt work so i asked again and these people are much more helpful -_-

Comment: You are still using a callback. As I said in the other question, use the returned Promise instead.

Comment: I said the exact same things that they've said in their answers - to pass a number itself as the `port` (or avoid passing it entirely since you want to use the default), and to use the Promise instead of the callback. Please actually read my answer before disregarding it.

Answer (score -1):

The second parameter of the ping function needs to be an object

```
   util.ping('play.hypixel.net', { port: 25565 })
```

Right now you’re passing a string which is causing it to error

[Library reference](https://github.com/PassTheMayo/Minecraft-Ping#pingstatus)

Comment: now it says: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Comment: Make sure you’re hitting the right server host/ip and port

Comment: i did put the right one lol i triple checked

Comment: Did you change your port to a number instead of a string? If that’s all good, then look at your network settings and firewall to make sure that all is open to allow traffic to and from that server. If issues continue, please open a new question and specifically state the econmrefused error as what you’re trying to solve

Comment: yes i did and firewall settings are good

Answer (score -1):

You should do:

```
util.ping(ip, { port: port }).then((response) => {
    const Embed = new RichEmbed()
    .setTitle('Server Status')
    .addField('Server IP', reponse.host)
    .addField('Server Version', reponse.version)
    .addField('Online Players', reponse.onlinePlayers)
    .addField('Max Players', reponse.maxPlayers)
                
    message.channel.send(Embed)
}).catch((error) => {
    throw error;
});
```

Comment: i got: TypeError: RichEmbed is not a constructor

Comment: Try using Embed instead of RichEmbed

Comment: I did and it gave me this new error: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Embed' before initialization

Comment: Did you import it from discord.js?

Comment: yes i did but ill try importing again

Comment: Use the embed const with not capital e

Comment: ok so i imported again but i still got: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Embed' before initialization

Comment: Try what I said in my last message

Comment: If it worked let me know

Comment: it now says: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'embed' before initialization

Comment: Can you modify your post with the new code, please?

Comment: @suntuz yeah sure

Comment: ok just updated it

Comment: You need to change: const {Client, RichEmbed} = require(‘discord.js’) to: const {Client, Embed} = require(‘discord.js’)

Comment: ok i did that but i still get the same error

Comment: I can only suggest to run “npm update” in the console, if this doesn’t work I have no idea sorry